# Filter by architecture for debtags search

Tags: debian, multiarch

I have [`multiarch`](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) enabled, and when I run [`debtags search`](https://wiki.debian.org/Debtags), I get a lot of duplicate results.

```
$ debtags search 'works-with-format::man' | head
docbook-to-man - converter from DocBook SGML into roff man macros
docbook-to-man:i386 - converter from DocBook SGML into roff man macros
docbook-utils - Convert DocBook files to other formats (HTML, RTF, PS, man, PDF)
docbook2x - Converts DocBook/XML documents into man pages and TeXinfo
docbook2x:i386 - Converts DocBook/XML documents into man pages and TeXinfo
doclifter - Convert troff to DocBook
dwww - Read all on-line documentation with a WWW browser
dwww:i386 - Read all on-line documentation with a WWW browser
ebook-speaker - eBook reader that reads aloud in a synthetic voice
ebook-speaker:i386 - eBook reader that reads aloud in a synthetic voice
```

There's a workaround using `grep`:

```
$ debtags search 'works-with-format::man' | grep -v ':i386 - ' | head
docbook-to-man - converter from DocBook SGML into roff man macros
docbook-utils - Convert DocBook files to other formats (HTML, RTF, PS, man, PDF)
docbook2x - Converts DocBook/XML documents into man pages and TeXinfo
doclifter - Convert troff to DocBook
dwww - Read all on-line documentation with a WWW browser
ebook-speaker - eBook reader that reads aloud in a synthetic voice
git-man - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (manual pages)
gman - small man(1) front-end for X
gmanedit - GTK+ man pages editor
gnulib - GNU Portability Library
```

This assumes the string `:i386 -` does not appear in any package description,
which is a bit of a hack. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
debtags search 'works-with-format::man' | awk 'BEGIN { FS="[: ]" }  ! ($1 in seen) { print; seen[$1]=1 }'
```

This will memorize seen packages (in `seen` array's index), regardless of the architecture (hence using both space and `:` as separator) and not print them again if already seen. Thus, it will also display a package that would exist only in i386 and not in the default (amd64) architecture (eg: `zsnes:i386` tagged with `hardware::emulation` doesn't exist as `zsnes` (ie `zsnes:amd64`)). Because packages without explicit architecture shown come first (in the debtags presorting algorithms...), there's no need to worry about displaying extra `:i386` unless needed.

UPDATE: as wished the same awk script in a standalone script file put as /usr/local/bin/debtagsfilter with this content

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN           {
                        FS="[: ]"
                }
! ($1 in seen)  {
                        print
                        seen[$1]=1
                }
```

and made executable with (`chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/filterdebtags`) can be used for example with: `debtags search 'works-with-format::man' | filterdebtags`

Or, if a "new" version of debtags called `/usr/local/bin/debtagswithfilter` is preferred (thus falling back to `sh` as invoked scripting language):

```
#!/bin/sh
debtags "$@" | awk '
BEGIN           {
                        FS="[: ]"
                }
! ($1 in seen)  {
                        print
                        seen[$1]=1
                }
'
```

compare (I get plain doubles, perhaps because of multiple repository sources):

```
$ debtags search 'hardware::emulation'
```

[...]

```
xtrs - emulator for TRS-80 Model I/III/4/4P computers
xtrs:i386 - emulator for TRS-80 Model I/III/4/4P computers
yabause - beautiful and under-rated Saturn emulator
yabause - beautiful and under-rated Saturn emulator
yabause-gtk - beautiful and under-rated Saturn emulator - Gtk port
yabause-gtk - beautiful and under-rated Saturn emulator - Gtk port
yabause-gtk:i386 - beautiful and under-rated Saturn emulator - Gtk port
yabause-gtk:i386 - beautiful and under-rated Saturn emulator - Gtk port
yabause-qt - beautiful and under-rated Saturn emulator - Qt port
yabause-qt - beautiful and under-rated Saturn emulator - Qt port
yabause-qt:i386 - beautiful and under-rated Saturn emulator - Qt port
yabause-qt:i386 - beautiful and under-rated Saturn emulator - Qt port
zsnes:i386 - Emulator of the Super Nintendo Entertainment System
```

with:

```
$ debtagswithfilter search 'hardware::emulation'
```

[...]

```
xtrs - emulator for TRS-80 Model I/III/4/4P computers
yabause - beautiful and under-rated Saturn emulator
yabause-gtk - beautiful and under-rated Saturn emulator - Gtk port
yabause-qt - beautiful and under-rated Saturn emulator - Qt port
zsnes:i386 - Emulator of the Super Nintendo Entertainment System
```

It works fine with more complex search requests too:

```
$ debtagswithfilter search 'works-with-format::tex && interface::text-mode'
asymptote - script-based vector graphics language inspired by MetaPost
auctex - integrated document editing environment for TeX etc.
axiom-tex - General purpose computer algebra system: style file for TeX
bibcursed - Interactive program to edit BibTeX bibliographies
chktex - Finds typographic errors in LaTeX
fweb - literate-programming tool for C/C++/Fortran/Ratfor
groff - GNU troff text-formatting system
vim-latexsuite - view, edit and compile LaTeX documents from within Vim
yatex - Yet Another TeX mode for Emacs
```

Comment: That looks good! Could you also include a version of the awk as a standalone script? I don't know enough awk to do that.

Comment: The standalone script works great, but the shell script will not work for more complex queries that are interpreted as shell syntax, e.g. `debtags search 'works-with-format::tex && interface::text-mode'`

Comment: `debtagswithfilter search 'works-with-format::tex && interface::text-mode'` works fine here. Perhaps you changed some character in the script? eg: `"$@"` is really different from `$@`, `$*` or `"$*"` . Other commands than `search` might not work correctly though.

Comment: You're right, it's only when I do something silly like actually name the new script `debtags` that I get an infinite loop.